# Looping more times than I expect

Tags: c++, loops

I have the following function, which takes a vector of students (who have a name and registration number), it is then calculating the min, max and average mark of those students (their marks are stored in a map), the output is partially correct, it should print each student just once, however the code I have written prints out each student the same number of times as the amount of marks stored in their vectors. I've spent some time trying to fix this,  I believe the problem is my third for loop, can someone explain why it's looping like this and how to fix it. Thanks.

```
string func1(vector<Student>students, float mark) {
    int count = 0;
    float avg, min, max = 0;
    list<string> toPrint;
    map<string, float> temp;
    vector<float> v;
    //for every student
    for(size_t a=0; a < students.size(); ++a) {
        temp = students[a].getCopyOfMap();
        v.erase(v.begin(), v.end());
        avg = 0;
        min = 0;
        max = 0;
        count = 0;

        for(map<string, float>::iterator it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); ++it) {
            stringstream ss;
            ss << it->second;
            v.push_back(stof(ss.str()));
        }

        for(map<string, float>::iterator it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); ++it) {
            max = *max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
            min = *min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
            for (size_t b=0; b < v.size(); ++b) {
                avg = avg + v[b];
                count++;
            }
            avg = avg/count;

            if(avg > mark) {
                stringstream out;
                out << students[a].getRegNo() << " " << min << " " << max << " " << avg << endl;
                toPrint.push_back(out.str());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a `main()` that exercises this function with values to demonstrate your problem (and show how the result differs from what you expected).  You might want to read how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'if' statement should be outside of your third 'for' but still inside of the first 'for'.

Comment: Thanks! It's always so simple, but I miss it.